# How do you optimize a query from an "Advanced Search Form"?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Generally speaking, how are MySQL queries generated from "Advanced Search Forms" with 20 - 30 optional fields optimized when there are so many different possibilities, columns, tables, outcomes, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, they aren't returned from the database.  With advanced searches that have many field options and maybe also some boolean logic thrown in for good measure are returned from a search server such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Xapian](http://xapian.org/).

Returning from the database is almost impossible to do efficiently.  It is usually done by building query dynamically such as:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 1=1
```

Then, loop over each other field and add

```
AND field LIKE '%abc'
AND field_2 LIKE '%def%'
AND field LIKE 'GHI%'
```

Idealy adding the whildchar `%` at the start or end if possible (for performance reasons), or both for searches within the field data.

Building and running this query makes it virtually impossible to have good indexing which makes them slow and a prime candidate for performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Steve.  What if you're doing an advanced search of user profiles on a social networking site, would you still use a search server?

Comment: @Programmer it would really depend on the dataset in question and what fields you're searching.  Sometimes a good normalised schema design can help greatly - for example storing a CountryId, StateId, TownId etc and filtering people nearby is much more efficient that having to generate the same data by manipulating strings.  Search servers are design for complex searches and they are usually very fast and more scalable than having it all within an RDBMS.